# JTree disable highlight effect on certain nodes

Tags: java, swing, jtree, defaultmutabletreenode

I have a `Jtree` and I need to remove the highlight effect on certain node.

So, now I have this for alla nodes

[image]

and I would like have this on certain node:

[image]

How can I achieve this ?
Thanks

Comment: you probably want to use [JTree Selection Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/treeselectionlistener.html)

Comment: @SuperRetro: are you sure about that? This looks like more of a job for the TreeCellRenderer.

Comment: Example of changing text style. Hopefully you get some idea from there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10976594/changing-text-style-of-defaultmutabletreenode

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: you are right! I spoke to soon! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-***First:*** you need to set an object (with your own property) to the node with the following method:

```
Group aGroup = new Group(); //Obviously use your correct constructor 
DefaultMutableTreeNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(yourObject);
```

Remember to implement `toString` method in Group class

-***Second:*** Create a new class that extends `DefaultTreeCellRenderer` and override  `getTreeCellRendererComponent` like this:

```
public class MyRenderer extends DefaultTreeCellRenderer {

        @Override
        public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value,
            boolean sel, boolean exp, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {

            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) value;

            if(node.getUserObject().getYourProperty()){
                 setTextNonSelectionColor(Color.BLACK);
                 setBackgroundSelectionColor(Color.BLUE);
                 setTextSelectionColor(Color.WHITE);
                 setBorderSelectionColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
           else{
                 setTextNonSelectionColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                 setBackgroundSelectionColor(Color.RED);
                 setTextSelectionColor(Color.WHITE);
                 setBorderSelectionColor(Color.WHITE);
           }

            super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(
                tree, value, sel, exp, leaf, row, hasFocus);
            return this;
        }
}
```

***-Third***: set your renderer to tree:

```
yourTree.setCellRenderer(new MyRenderer());
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you not maybe use something like this ? Unsure of practicality and not tested it

```
tree.addMouseListener (new MouseAdapter (){

        public void mousePressed ( MouseEvent e ){

           // Check for right click
           if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)){

                  int selection[] = tree.getSelectionRows();

                  for(int i=0; i< selection.size; i++){

                     tree.removeSelectionInterval(selection[i], selection[i]);
                  }
           }
}
```