# How to hide some nodes in a Swing Tree?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

How can I hide middle node and show parent and grand child node in JTree?

Eg: 
I have a Tree
A
|
B
|
C

But I want to show it as 
A
|
C,

I want to hide some middle node like B. 
Please help me.

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9234297/1076463), which is unfortunately still unanswered

Comment: You'll need to remove B from A and add C to A

Comment: @MadProgrammer, but I don't want to remove B from the tree.

Comment: use two models, secondary is "filtered" based on given value

Comment: @Gangadhar What you want and what you can do aren't always the same thing ;)