# any non-swing alternative to DefaultStyledDocument?

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread, defaultstyleddocument

I've assimilated this idea that it is always bad to use a Swing component outside the EDT.
In my non-GUI program (as it currently is) I do however want to use some kind of marked-up string (containing non-visual logical styles that give some kind of "meta" info about bits of the string).  DefaultStyledDocument works perfectly.  But its package is of course javax.swing.text.

Am I alone in feeling it is inappropriate to use it in a non-EDT thread?  Is there any alternative (other than to roll my own class or use the EDT despite having no GUI)?

Comment: You can safely use the Swing models outside the EDT, as long as they are not yet connected to a view. A more common example is to do a DB query and construct a `TableModel` on a background thread, and set the model to a `JTable` on the EDT.

Comment: Note that I didn't say they are thread-safe. But single-threaded access outside the EDT is allowed as long as they are not connected to a view

Comment: @Robin - understood ... by the way, I submitted a new answer to your qu from 2012 about a JTree with filter... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234297/filtering-on-a-jtree/19618192#19618192... I'd like your opinion of it if you have time