# How to implement a Filter/Searchfield in JXTreeTable? What is good practice?

Tags: java, swing, filter, swingx, jxtreetable

I have a class TreeNode which has some attribitues and a ArrayList of children.

For this class I have my own TreeModel which extends AbstractTreeTableModel. The created tree is displayed correctly.

Now I want to add a search field which searches in one attribute and show all parents and all children when it matches with one node. So I have to traverse the tree up and down.

I tried to use a SerachFactory but it only searches visible nodes.

An Example would help me a lot or best practise. Do I need a second Model (which extends AbstractTreeTableModel) where a filter can be applied? How can I do that?  Or is the way to go over a Renderer?

Comment: unfortunately, that's a non-trivial endevour - there are several options, none really satisfactory. Search for QAs for filtering a plain TreeModel on this site (sorry, don't have a link handy) to get you going (a TreeTableModel is-a TreeModel)

Comment: found one reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234297/filtering-on-a-jtree

Comment: Thank you. I tried to implement a filtered model, but i have a problem to update the view. How can I do this? I tried tree.setTreeTableModel(filteredModel);    TreeModelSupport tms = new TreeModelSupport(filteredModel);
tms.fireNewRoot(); In the DefaultTreeModel, which I can't use, there is a reload method - like in http://www.adrianwalker.org/2012/04/filtered-jtree.html

Comment: you can implement the reload just the same way as DefaultTreeModel does it, just look at its source code :-)

Comment: Ok I can try to implement these methods. But they are 5 complex methods with an other underlying data structure (Arrays). Is there no easy way to update the model?

Comment: protected  void fireTreeStructureChanged(java.lang.Object source, java.lang.Object[] path, int[] childIndices, java.lang.Object[] children)      This method I think I must call but in my derived model the method ist not available? It extends AbstracTreeTableModel